# How To Add TFileAttribute switch to IOUtils functions

Tags: delphi

Shown below are two functions using `IOUtils` to count folders and files. How do you add a switch (`CountHidden`) to toggle counting files or folders with the `faHidden` `TFileAttribute`?

```
function SubDirectoryCount( const Path: string; const CountHidden: boolean; const Recurse: boolean ): Cardinal;
    { Counts all the sub-directories of a specified directory. If Recurse is true
      all sub-directories are counted recursively, otherwise only immediate
      sub-directories are counted. Count Hidden toggles counting hidden files (faHidden). }
    var
      StrArray: Types.TStringDynArray; // array of subdirectories
      SearchOption: IOUtils.TSearchOption; // directory search option
    begin
      if Recurse then
        SearchOption := IOUtils.TSearchOption.soAllDirectories
      else
        SearchOption := IOUtils.TSearchOption.soTopDirectoryOnly;
      StrArray := IOUtils.TDirectory.GetDirectories( Path, '*', SearchOption );
      Result := length( StrArray );
    end;

    function SubDirectoryFileCount( const Path: string; const CountHidden: boolean; const Recurse: boolean ): Cardinal;
    { Counts all the files of a specified directory. If Recurse is true
      files in all sub-directories are counted recursively, otherwise only immediate
      sub-directories are counted. Count Hidden toggles counting hidden files (faHidden).}
    var
      StrArray: Types.TStringDynArray; // array of subdirectories
      SearchOption: IOUtils.TSearchOption; // directory search option
    begin
      if Recurse then
        SearchOption := IOUtils.TSearchOption.soAllDirectories
      else
        SearchOption := IOUtils.TSearchOption.soTopDirectoryOnly;
      StrArray := IOUtils.TDirectory.GetFiles( Path, '*', SearchOption );
      Result := length( StrArray );
    end;
```

Also are there any improvements that could be made to these two functions?
I am using Delphi 2010 on Windows 7.

Comment: The original question has the following comment from a moderator  [Lasse V. Karlsen](http://stackoverflow.com/users/267/lasse-v-karlsen) attached to it: "This question, and answer, contains code copyrighted by Embarcadero. Not only will it stay closed in its current form, it will also be deleted." Is that statement correct?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I don't think so, the original question was very similar to this one and the answer was wrote by myself (not using any copyrighted code). So I don't see any code copyrighted by Embarcadero. I think which the moderator makes a mistake.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I just found the same function (`SubDirectoryCount`) in this [site](http://www.delphidabbler.com/codesnip?action=named&routines=DarkenColor,LightenColor,PlaySound,IsAdmin,ReverseNumber,ReverseNumberR,FileSizeString,GetLastDirectory,SubDirectoryCount,SplitPathList_A,SplitPathList_B) . @Bill if you're using code that is someone else, you must indicate this.

Comment: @RRUZ The question was just about standard VCLCode about how to use IOUtils.  DelphiDabbler is a site where code is shared amoung users where I am a major contributor.  I can not remember if I wrote the original code or if Peter did, however, the Delphi Dabbler site is open source "The license shall not restrict any party from selling or giving away the software as a component of an aggregate software distribution containing programs from several different sources. The license shall not require a royalty or other fee for such sale."

Comment: @Bill thanks by the clarification :)

Comment: @RRUZ I asked a question about the original deleted question over on meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114019/why-was-this-question-closed-and-deleted

Comment: This is a special case (and is still being hammered out), but please realize that re-asking a closed and deleted question is a pretty serious breach of conduct here, and can get your account suspended.  Please don't jump the gun and repost like this again; its always better to go to [meta], discuss what happened, and possibly get things straightened out.

Comment: I am sorry... I did not know how to find out why the original was deleted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a [TDirectory.TFilterPredicate](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/IOUtils.TDirectory.TFilterPredicate) class.

check these samples

```
function SubDirectoryCount( const Path: string; const CountHidden: boolean; const Recurse: boolean ): Cardinal;
var
  StrArray     : Types.TStringDynArray;
  SearchOption : IOUtils.TSearchOption;
  Predicate    : TDirectory.TFilterPredicate;
begin
  if Recurse then
    SearchOption := IOUtils.TSearchOption.soAllDirectories
  else
    SearchOption := IOUtils.TSearchOption.soTopDirectoryOnly;

  Predicate := function(const Path: string; const SearchRec: TSearchRec): Boolean
                     begin
                       Result := (SearchRec.Attr and faHidden)=0;
                     end;

  if CountHidden then
    StrArray := IOUtils.TDirectory.GetDirectories( Path, '*', SearchOption)
  else
    StrArray := IOUtils.TDirectory.GetDirectories( Path, '*', SearchOption, Predicate);

  Result := length(StrArray);
end;

function SubDirectoryFileCount( const Path: string; const CountHidden: boolean; const Recurse: boolean ): Cardinal;
var
  StrArray     : Types.TStringDynArray;
  SearchOption : IOUtils.TSearchOption;
  Predicate    : TDirectory.TFilterPredicate;
begin
  if Recurse then
    SearchOption := IOUtils.TSearchOption.soAllDirectories
  else
    SearchOption := IOUtils.TSearchOption.soTopDirectoryOnly;

  Predicate := function(const Path: string; const SearchRec: TSearchRec): Boolean
               begin
                Result := (SearchRec.Attr and faHidden)=0;
               end;

  if CountHidden then
    StrArray := IOUtils.TDirectory.GetFiles( Path, '*', SearchOption )
  else
    StrArray := IOUtils.TDirectory.GetFiles( Path, '*', SearchOption, Predicate);

  Result := length(StrArray);
end;
```